# reading sms from sim using gsm modam via serial port

Tags: c#, serial-port

I am trying to read sms from my sim card via serial port and i succeeded but suddenly i got this error
the requested resource is in use"
the basic purpose of the code is to read sms from a sim card inserted in 4g lte modam and show all the details of messages in grid in c# windows form application

the code is as fellow

```
  private SerialPort _serialPort;
        private int _baudRate = 115200;
        string unread = "AT+CMGL=\"REC UNREAD\"\r";
        string read = "AT+CMGL=\"REC READ\"\r";
        string all = "AT+CMGL=\"ALL\"\r";
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SMS(all);
        }
        private void SMS(string cmd)
        {
            try
            {
                string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();

                _serialPort = new SerialPort("COM3", _baudRate);
                _serialPort.Dispose();
                _serialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
                _serialPort.DataBits = 8;
                _serialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
                _serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.XOnXOff;
                _serialPort.DtrEnable = true;
                _serialPort.RtsEnable = true;
                _serialPort.NewLine = Environment.NewLine;
                _serialPort.Close();
                //_serialPort.

                if (!_serialPort.IsOpen)
                {
                    _serialPort.Open(); 
                }

                _serialPort.Write("AT" + System.Environment.NewLine);
                Thread.Sleep(1000);

                _serialPort.WriteLine("AT+CMGF=1" + System.Environment.NewLine);
                Thread.Sleep(1000);

                _serialPort.WriteLine(cmd + System.Environment.NewLine);
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
                var res = _serialPort.ReadExisting();
                MessageBox.Show( _serialPort.ReadExisting());
                //string data=_serialPort.ReadExisting();
                //tb_messages.Text = data;

                _serialPort.Close();

                //Regex r = new Regex(@"\+CMGL:(\d+),""(.+)"",""(.+)"",(.*),""(.+)""\r\n(.+)\r\n");
                //Match m = r.Match(_serialPort.ReadExisting());
                //string a = m.Groups[1].Value;
                //string b = m.Groups[2].Value;
                //string c = m.Groups[3].Value;
                //MessageBox.Show(_serialPort.ReadExisting());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //throw;
                MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Comment: why on earth would you call `_serialPort.Dispose();` right after initialization of the port and use it afterwards?

Comment: usually this message points towards the point that the port is still open and used by another process.